# Add SSL on AWS Bitnami Server without domain name

Tags: ssl, bitnami

I still new for Bitnami serve.

Now i setup Bitnami server on AWS. I still don't have Domain name. Right now, im using IP Domain to access it. the question is, Do i really can setup SSL encryption (HTTPS) by using IP domain?

i was followed this documentation https://docs.bitnami.com/general/how-to/generate-install-lets-encrypt-ssl/

but it required domain name.

please help

Answer (score 0):

Here a bitnami engineer, if you want to use HTTPS you need a domain. Let's Encrypt not allow IP, you need to search another or create a self-signed certificate.
To the last one, you can use `OpenSSL`.